# facebook comments moderation not working after adding all meta tags

Tags: facebook, comments

I implemented Facebook comments.

I added all `<meta>` with `admin`, `app_id`, `og:image`, `og:description`, `og:title`, `og:type`, and `og:url`.
Also I added `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` to `<html>`.

As a result of all the efforts comments work no problem but I don't see any of the comments in the comments' [moderation tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments). 
Debugger does not indicate any warnings, as [it can be seen here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Falexeirebrov.com%2Fcollections%2Fabstract-prints-for-bedroom%2Fproducts%2Fabstract-music-textures).

I can't figure out how to enable moderation

Answer (score 0):

> To administer your page, you need to associate it with **either** your
>   Facebook account **or** your Facebook Platform application.

The problem is that you specified both of them:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="534577546"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="109585062417070"/>
```

Choose one or the other. If you don't know which, you should read:

- the *Page Administration* part of this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/
- the *Administration tools* part of this document:
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/